# C# MongoDB update definition from filled model

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

How i can combine type C# filled model and mongo language for create update request?

i try this but get types  error:

```
 var update = new ObjectUpdateDefinition<User>(user) & Builders<User>.Update.Inc(f => f.FindCount, 1);
```

FullCode:

```
            var user = new Model
            {
                Email = email,
                Language = language,
                Password = password,
                // +17 fields
            };
            
            // how i can convert all fields to set? and join with query Inc (like AllFieldToSet)? 
            var update = user.AllFieldToSet() & Builders<User>.Update.Inc(f => f.FindCount, 1);
            
            Models.FindOneAndUpdate<Model>(
             f => f.Email == email, 
             update, 
             new FindOneAndUpdateOptions<Model> {IsUpsert = true});
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly I would begin to ask why do you update so many fields at once, this can have a significant effect on performance and scalability, especially when your collection has indexes, replication and/or sharding involved. Whenever you have to update an indexed field it needs to update the index as well.

There are multiple solutions:

**ReplaceOne:**
Inc only increments the value, this can be done manually in the model: FindCount++

**Manually build the update operator:** Just manually build using the builder they provided

**Write your own extension using reflection** Personally I like type safety but you can use this extension that I wrote (you will just have to extend it and build in null checks, etc.)

```
public static class UpdateBuilderExtensions
{
    public static UpdateDefinition<TDocument> SetAll<TDocument, TModel>(this UpdateDefinition<TDocument> updateBuilder, TModel value, params string[] excludeProperties)
    {
        foreach (var property in value.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance).Where(x => excludeProperties?.Contains(x.Name) == false))
            updateBuilder = Builders<TDocument>.Update.Combine(updateBuilder.Set(property.Name, property.GetValue(value)));

        return updateBuilder;
    }
}
```

Usage of it:
You have to exclude properties that have been set already and you have to exclude the BsondId field (if you do not set it manually)

```
var update = Builders<User>.Update.Inc(x => x.FindCount, 1).SetAll(model, nameof(model.Id), nameof(model.FindCount));
Models.UpdateOne(x => x.Email== "some-email", update, new UpdateOptions
{
IsUpsert = true
});
```

Comment: because i need .Update.Inc(f => f.FindCount, 1)

Comment: updated my answer, I think you are looking to just extend the existing builder so the extension solution should work for you @padavan

Comment: thx Shaun.  this is the best option so far. Let's see who else will offer

Comment: i find  new intresting thing:  ObjectUpdateDefinition<User>(model);  but this add __id to query and i get error :(